# Task.Run does't run the task in background c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I need to call a function inside the task without hanging the UI, this is what I do but faced hanging with the main thread which is the login form, so what is missing or if I implement by wrong way?

```
private async void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await LoginAsync();
}

private async Task<bool> LoginAsync()
{
     LoginResponse loginResponse = await Task.Run(() =>
                    loginService.Login(new LoginModel { UserName = txtUN.Text, Password = txtPW.Text })
     );

     return loginResponse.Success;
}
```

Backend code:

```
public interface ILoginService
{
     Task<LoginResponse> Login(LoginModel model);
     Task<LogoutResponse> Logout();
}

public partial class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    public Task<LoginResponse> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
         return LoginAsync(model);
    }

    private async Task<LoginResponse> LoginAsync(LoginModel model)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        string _Url = BaseUrl + "/login";
        try
        {
            model.CompanyName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Company_Name"];
            string Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            _logger.Info($"Login Request, Body: {Body}");
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(_Url), new 
            StringContent(Body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(await 
            responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            HandleException(e);
            return new LoginResponse
            {
               HttpStatus = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
               Message = "Internal server error"
            };
         }
    }
}
```

so anyone please can guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try await Task.Factory.StartNew ?

Comment: How long does the UI thread hang for? Also what is the purpose of the for loop?

Comment: Kalten, yes buddy I tried but the same.

Comment: the loop just to check if the UI hanging or not

Comment: @AmmarSaleh what does that mean?

Comment: the UI hang until the loop finish

Comment: @AmmarSaleh, just out of curiosity, if you add a `System.Threading.Thread.Yield();` call after the `Console.WriteLine()` call, does the UI still hang?   Do you have any other event that could be triggering, like a Timer or something?

Comment: @BlueStrat tried but the same, I don't know what is the problem with it, and I don't have any other events triggered except the for loop.

Comment: @Paramecium13 suggestion is good. Are you on Visual Studio?  Try hitting the pause execution button while the UI is frozen and see where the code breaks. Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks  should show the call stacks of all the active threads in your application.  This should throw some light

Comment: The `interface ILoginService` has asynchronous methods without the `Async` suffix. Why? Omitting it makes your code quite confusing, because you do include the suffix elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

### Console.WriteLine(i);

is the only thing that is highly suspicious in your code. This is a bit stating the obvious but when you use `Task.Run`, the passed-in action is going to be scheduled to the default task scheduler, the default `ThreadPool` if you hadn't defined any, and then a thread in the threadpool will pick up the work while your main UI thread is freely waiting for another UI actions. **So there shouldn't be freezing on your UI application because of the fact above**.

If it **looks like** freezing, you probably run the app through your `Visual Studio` with F5 ( if F5 means Start Debugging in your hot-key configuration ). Becuase `Console.WriteLine` will be vomitting all the index values on the "Output" window somewhere in the IDE, and make **your action** against the app unresponsive, even though your UI in the app is not actually freezing.

Try running your app outside of your IDE, simply `CTRL + F5` ( Start without debugging ) if you still want to run the app via `Visual Studio` or just execute the `.exe` directly. Then I guess you can see your UI working fine.

Answer (score -3):

This is because the button click event handler is awaiting the task (i. e. it is waiting for the task to complete). You also don't do anything with the result of the task.

Comment: so? what i should to do

Comment: @Ammar Saleh first, remove the ````await```` from BtnLogin_Click. That will stop the UI from hanging. Then you probably want to do something with the result of the login task. You can place that code in its own method or in a lambda in LoginAsync. Note that if the response to the login task needs to change the UI, I think that change needs to be done on the UI's main thread. To do that I think you pass a function to some method (I forget which one) on the form (this also likely varies between WinForms and WPF).

Comment: @Paramecium13, no the await should not block the UI thread, in fact the event handler returns as soon as it hits the await keyword - so the main thread should be able to continue processing Windows messages.   In this case there is nothing to execute after the await, so I doubt a continuation is scheduled to continue processing. I think the reason why the UI thread is blocking is not shown on the code that has been shared.

Comment: @BlueStrat won't it only return immediately if the event is fired asynchronously? If its just a standard WinForms button control wouldn't the Clicked event be executed synchronously? Given that the UI is hanging, it seems possible that this is the case.

Comment: @Paramecium13 I've removed it from btnClick but the same

Comment: @Ammar Saleh I'm not too sure what's going on. In the debugger, can you see where the UI thread is hanging? Also, is the Login button actually supposed to do something with the result of LoginAsync?

Comment: @Paramecium13 - The `Clicked` event should in fact be running on the main thread. As soon as it hits the `await`, the handler returns and the main thread is free to continue processing messages. `Task.Run()` should have queued the work on the application's thread pool.  When this work is finished, the async machinery posts a new Windows message that will eventually be processed by the main thread, this message will invoke the continuation that will run the code following the await, that in this case is nothing. I still believe the reason for the UI lock is not shown. Maybe a heavy timer event?

Comment: @BlueStrat Huh, I think you're right. So I think I was a bit confused (and, after reading up on tasks and threading am now more confused). I know that when an async method is called synchronously, it runs synchronously. I expected that the event would be invoked synchronously but I guess it's invoked asynchronously?

Comment: @Paramecium13,  don't worry, async-await was hard to grasp for me also.  I totally recommend Stephen Cleary's _Concurrency in C# Cookbook_. It does a fantastic job in explaining the internals. This is one abstraction that you REALLY need to know what is going behind the scenes or you will end up pulling your hair eventually. ;)

Comment: @Paramecium13 The OnClick event is run by the main thread, that is actually running a very simple loop that is continuously trying to process messages that Windows places on an event queue. A click on a button shows up as a message on this loop. This loop will eventually process the message and will end up calling the code in the `Click` event handler.

Comment: (2) This is the reason why doing heavy processing on an event handler freezes the UI, because no more messages will be processed until the handler returns. Both Windows Forms and WPF have what is called a synchronization context  (a fancy term abstracting the fact that all code that interacts with a UI element must run  from the UI thread). In this case,  the WCF machinery will try to run every continuation after an await on the UI thread (unless you override this behavior with a ConfigureAwait(false) call, but then you are forbidden from interacting with any UI control after the await).

Comment: (3) As I explained before, Windows solves this "run in the main thread" by posting a new message to the queue. The message has all the necessary information to invoke the continuation after the `await` call. The async machinery currently does this by creating a hidden-auxiliary class around your method.  This class uses private members to hold the state of any local variable that is accessed after a continuation resumes, and uses a state machine to know where the execution needs to jump to continue running your code, after an await is satisfied.

Comment: (4) So in a sense, it is very helpful to visualize the await as a return statement, and then visualize the code AFTER the await as a new, different method, that somehow has been given access to the local variables and parameters of the previous method.  This "continuation" method is called automatically once the awaited operation is complete, at some point in the future.

Comment: (5) Unfortunately, this access to the "method state" is sometimes broken. Many WinForms controls event handlers receive  specialized `EventArgs` parameters.  Often, these parameters are disposable, and the component that calls your event handler will often 'Dispose()' the parameter after your event handler runs.   If your event handler is async, reaching the first await will cause a return to the caller, that will in turn call Dispose().  This means that the event args parameter is not usable after the await resumes!